# How to give next js app build to the client

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am new on Next JS, I have created a small application. It is using API calls and more features.
During development, Using the command  as `npm run build` I am able to create `.next` folder as build and using `npm run start` I am able to run that build.

Now the client is asking for build, so what should I send to him? Either complete project and ask him to do the
`npm run build` and `npm run start` (which I don't think so)
or only the `.next` folder. But how he will run this build?

Comment: If you are sending `.next` you also need to send `package.json`, `next.config.js`, `public` folder, etc. Basically everything except you code files, assets that are passed through webpack loaders, node modules, and development-only config. Then they can run it by installing all production dependencies and `next start`. Sending the complete source code is easier than this.

Comment: ok sir, let me try this first on my system

Comment: I have selected `next.config.js`,`next-i18next.config.js`, `package.json`
and `.next`, `public`  folders and put all this stuff in a folder on desktop, then run npm install command. after that I run npm run start command BUT gotten error as  Could not find a production build in .next folder

Comment: You have to build it (`npm run build`) before copying your `.next` folder.

Comment: ok sir, let me check and get back to you

Comment: Perfect so I just need `public, styles, .next` folders and  `next config js , next-i18next.config js, and package json` file .. then run the command npm install then just npm run start

Comment: Thanks you for you help @brc-dd

Comment: I'm not fully understanding - is there a reason not to send the entire repository?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open `package.json` in your editor and add the following export script to the file:

   ```
   "export": "npm run build && next export -o _static"
   ```
2. run this code in the terminal:

   ```
   npm run export
   ```
3. Open `_static` folder and there is all of your file.

Comment: yes I got _static folder using above steps, But how client will run this ?

Comment: Hello .... I have the _static folder but how will I run this folder ? It has _next subfolder which has further two subfolders mYJJqywoouxkcRhgBEv78 and static subfolders which has further

Comment: I have node installed on my system, as I have developed the next app here

Comment: it depends on your server.
if you have Cpanel or Plesk, you should upload your files then open your nodejs extension on your host, then introduce your package.json

Comment: "introduce your package.json"  means ?

Comment: can you please provide a reference or tutorial link?

Comment: You can serve the static files inside the generated folder locally with `npx serve _static`, for example.

Comment: It has a file upload input to choose your "package.json" for downloading node_module

Comment: I have not gotten package.json file in the generated folder. Should I put that manually in the folder?

Comment: use your project package.json

Comment: using npm run export, I am getting error as `Error: i18n support is not compatible with next export.`

Comment: i18n support is not compatible with `next export`, because you no longer have a server to handle the routing. You will need to continue using `next build` and `next start`.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Answer (score 1):

Some possible ways of sharing your project:

- You can easily build and host your project with services like vercel or netlify. Easy and quick. Check out the [vercel CLI](https://vercel.com/cli) in particular.
- Your client can clone the git repo, install all dependencies, run build, and run start. This'll start a production server. Check here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production. Bad idea if your client is not a dev.
- You can build your project and send the output to your client, which he/she can then view by spinning up a server ([python simpleHTTPServer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server), [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/)). Also a bad idea if your client is not a dev.

Long story short, host your project somewhere and send them a production URL.

Comment: Using `"export": "npm run build && next export -o _static"` I am getting error as `Error: i18n support is not compatible with next export. `